# What does whitespace actually mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have something like this:

```
projectName= echo $tempPBXProjFilePath | sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)\.xcodeproj.*$/\1/g";
```

I want to extract substring from `$tempPBXProjFilePath`. And this is correct. However, if I write it like this:

```
projectName=echo $tempPBXProjFilePath | sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)\.xcodeproj.*$/\1/g";
```

It is wrong. The difference is the whitespace after the variable.

I know there is no whitespace after variable directly. But what's the meaning of the whitespace after equal-sign. Is there any place whitespace has special meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Variable Assignment

The syntax for [variable assignment](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html) is:

```
name=value
```

Note, there are no spaces around the `=` sign. If the value has spaces, or special characters, it should be quoted with single quotes:

```
name='value with spaces or special characters'
```

or with double quotes for [variable expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_03):

```
name="stringA $variable stringB"
```

If quotes are missing, the second word in the value part is interpreted as a command. Actually, this is a way to pass environment variables to a command (see below).

If the value is missing, a variable with an empty value is created.

## Environment Variables

There is another syntax that allows to assign environment variables for a command:

```
nameA=valueA nameB=valueB nameC=valueC command arguments
```

The name-value pairs are separated with space characters.

**Example**

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/malloc.so /bin/ls
```

The command assigns `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to `/path/to/my/malloc.so` before invoking `/bin/ls`.

## Your Commands

Thus, your command:

```
projectName= echo $tempPBXProjFilePath
```

actually means that you call `echo` command with arguments [expanded](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_03) from `$tempPBXProjFilePath`, and set `projectName`  environment variable to an empty value.

And this command:

```
projectName=echo $tempPBXProjFilePath
```

sets `projectName` environment variable to `echo` string, and calls a command expanded from `$tempPBXProjFilePath` variable.

Note, if a variable is not enclosed in double quotes, the special characters that present in its value are interpreted by the shell. In order to prevent reinterpretation of the special characters, you should use weak quoting: `"$variable"`. And if you want to prevent even variable expansion in a string value, use single quotes: `'some value'`.

Comment: Great summary, Ruslan!  I have added a few more things to your write-up.  Hope you like it.

Answer (score 2):

Bash divides each line into words at each whitespace (spaces or tabs).

The first word it finds is the name of the command to be executed and the remaining words become arguments to that command.

so when you pass

```
projectName=echo
```

bash understand projectName=echo as a variable assignment, and

```
$tempPBXProjFilePath | sed "s/.*\/\(.*\)\.xcodeproj.*$/\1/g";
```

as a command! (as pointed by  Chris Dodd)

Whitespace

Putting spaces on either or both sides of the equal-sign (=) when assigning a value to a variable will fail.

## INCORRECT 1

```
example = Hello
```

## INCORRECT 2

```
example= Hello
```

## INCORRECT 3

```
example =Hello
```

The only valid form is no spaces between the variable name and assigned value:

## CORRECT 1

```
example=Hello
```

## CORRECT 2

```
example=" Hello"
```

You can see more at:

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/newbie_traps

Comment: Actually, `projectName=` or `projectName=echo` is a variable assignment rather than the command name (the first sets `projectName` to the empty string).  You can have one or more variable assignments before the command name in a command -- the command name is the first word that does *not* contain an `=`

Comment: Thank you for your answer today and yesterday. Sorry I don't choose this although it helps me a lot. It's really hard to decide which answer is better.